# Sorting and comparing strings by locales in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell, localization, locale

is it possible to properly sort strings with national characters in Haskell (GHC) ? In other words, correct collation of Chars by current locale settings ?

I did found ICU module only, but it requires extra library to be installed because it isn't a standard part of linux distributions. I would like solution based on POSIX's C (glibc like) library, so there won't be any hassle with handling of additional dependency.

Comment: You could write an FFI binding to `wcscoll`, but using `text-icu` is both nicer and probably more correct.

Comment: Good question, and good answer.  Human stuff is never a pure function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Recommended way: text-icu**

The recommended way for robustly processing strings in a locale-sensitive manner is via **[text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text)** and **[text-icu](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-icu)**, as you have seen. The [text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) library is provided in the standard library set, the [Haskell Platform](http://haskell.org/platform).

An example, sorting Turkish strings:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text.IO  as T 
import Data.Text.ICU as T 
import Data.List     (sortBy)

main = do
  let trLocale = T.Locale "tr-TR"
      str      = "ÇIİĞÖŞÜ"
      strs     = take 10 (cycle $ T.toLower trLocale str : str : [])

  mapM_ T.putStrLn (sortBy (T.compare [T.FoldCaseExcludeSpecialI]) strs)
```

appears to correctly sort by [lexicographic ordering](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text-icu/0.6.3.3/doc/html/Data-Text-ICU.html#g:7) based on locale, after correctly lower-casing the Turkish string:

```
*Main> main
ÇIİĞÖŞÜ
ÇIİĞÖŞÜ
ÇIİĞÖŞÜ
ÇIİĞÖŞÜ
ÇIİĞÖŞÜ
çıiğöşü
çıiğöşü
çıiğöşü
çıiğöşü
çıiğöşü
```

**Not using the text-icu package**

You've asked in your question to avoid solutions that use additional libraries, other than what Posix provides. While text-icu is easily installable from Hackage (`cabal install text-icu`), it does depend on the ICU C library, which isn't available everywhere. Additionally, there is no Posix alternative that is as robust or comprehensive. Finally, `text-icu` is the only package that correctly does conversions on multi-char characters.

Given this, though, the built in Char and String types in Haskell provide [Data.Char](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Data-Char.html), whose values represent Unicode, and with functions that [will do Unicode case conversion](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Data-Char.html#g:4), in a locale-insensitive way, using [the `wchar_t` functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/wchar.h.html) defined by the Open Group. Additionally, we can do IO on Handles in a (text) locale-sensitive way.

```
import System.IO  
import Data.Char
import Data.List  (sort)

main = do
    t <- mkTextEncoding "UTF-8"
    hSetEncoding stdout t

    let str      = "ÇIİĞÖŞÜ"
        strs     = take 10 (cycle $ map toLower str : str : [])

    mapM_ putStrLn (sort strs)
```

In fact, GHC will use your text locale by default for IO (e.g. UTF8). For many problems, this will probably give the right answer. You just have to be aware it will also be wrong in many cases, since it isn't possible to be correct without bulk processing of text, and rich conversion and comparison support.

```
*Main> main
ÇIİĞÖŞÜ
ÇIİĞÖŞÜ
ÇIİĞÖŞÜ
ÇIİĞÖŞÜ
ÇIİĞÖŞÜ
çiiğöşü
çiiğöşü
çiiğöşü
çiiğöşü
çiiğöşü
```

---

Comment: And notice the `i` is different in the Char solution.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more correct to use [these functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text-icu/0.6.3.3/doc/html/Data-Text-ICU.html#g:9) for locale-specific collation?

Comment: Also note that toUpper on `Char` only does wide char conversion, based on the `LC_CTYPE` locale setting. So it is only partially locale-aware. And as mentioned, it fails for multi-char conversions.

Comment: @hammar yes, I think you should probably use the approved collating methods.